# Angular: form group binding for checkboxes not setting default value after migrating to version 6

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, formgroups

I've got an app which was built with angular2/3/4. I've got controller that initializes a `FormGroup` with code that looks like this (the initialization is done inside its constructor):

```
this.funcoes = this._fb.group({
      "cliente": [false],
      "gestorRecursos": [false],
      "motorista": [false],
      "gestorUtilizadores": [false]
  }, { validator: ValidacoesPersonalizadas.verificaExistenciaSelecao} );
```

And here's the HTML of one of the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="cliente" id="cliente" name="cliente" formControlName="cliente" />
```

After migrating to version 6, I've noticed that if the user doesn't "check/uncheck" the checkboxes associated with each of the formcontrol that make the group, then trying to get its value will return null (instead of the defaultvalue):

```
const isClient = this.funcoes.get("cliente").value; //null, if user does not click
```

I know that I haven't really been active in angular for a couple of months, but I was under the impression that the default value passed to the `group` method during the group's setup should be used as the value when the user hasn't touched the checkbox. Am I wrong? Has anything changed with the release of the last version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it. Nothing wrong with angular :)

Somewhere, there was a `reset` call which was being triggered by a specific value passed to one of the fields (in the wizard). In practice, this will end up nulling all the values (and that's why the initial default value wasn't being used).